# django как получить данные с формы готового шаблона html

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, requests, webforms

Как правильно получить данные с поля/лей шаблона после нажатия на кнопку "button" на странице ?

views.py

```
def post(request):
    form = Get_form(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data["post"]
        form = Get_form()
        args = {"form": form, "text": text}
        return render(request, "getting_data/get.html", args)
    else:

        # product_id = request.POST['id']     # < -- нужно получить зна-ие поля
        # print(f"product_id: {product_id}")
        form = Get_form()
        text = {"form": form}
        return render(request, "getting_data/get.html", text)
```

get.html

```
 <form action="" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="text" name="id">           # <-- нужное значение содержится здесь 
     <input type="submit" value="get"><br>   # <-- получить это значение после нажатия конпки
   </form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вышла след ошибка :/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

urlpatterns:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пропишите ссылку на `def post` в участке `action=""`

Comment: Также у вас `Get_form(request.GET)` метод не `GET`, а `POST`

Comment: а как правильно прописать ссылку на def post ?

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка в action у формы прописывается так: `action="{% url 'app_name:name_url' params %}"` - это просто шаблон того как надо делать, а в вашем же случае просто указать имя url-адреса, где форма (имя адреса вьюхи post), это будет так: `{% url 'имя адреса' %}`. Да и вместо `form = Get_form(request.GET)` напишите `form = Get_form(request.POST)`, так как вы хотите получить данные, а не просто отобразить их

Comment: вышла след ошибка / после исправления моментов на которые вы указали, хде то еще ошибка которую я не вижу

Comment: Что за ошибка ?

Comment: Reverse for 'getting_data/get.html' not found. 'getting_data/get.html' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Рисунок выше скрин с страницы. View не нравиьтся ему

Comment: Нет такого имени адреса, покажите ваш urlpattrens

Comment: скрин наверху добавил по url patterns

Comment: Тут возможно дело не в адресе. У вас правильно путь до шаблона прописан?

Comment: да так как до этого заходило по данному пути к шаблону --> 'getting_data/get.html'  но вот обрабатывать нажатие кнопки не получается

Comment: могу посоветовать почитать вопрос об исключении NoReverseMatch по подробнее. там все сказано из-за чего это проблема возникает, а то самому не хочется голову ломать :)

Comment: хорошо ) Все равно спасибо за помошь